# how to reload page after 20 second just once?

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to reload page after 20 second, but it is periodically ! 
I would like to reload page just once after 20 second !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() 
{ window.location=window.location;},20000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use a flag ?

Comment: I am a beginner in java-script. how can I do ?

Comment: do you mean once per page load or only once? setTimeout will do it once for every page load, you need some sort of persitant marker(cookie etc) to do it only ever once

Comment: Wanting to reload after 20 seconds and then not reload again is a very *odd* request. What do you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: some images not loaded at the first time !

Comment: Couple of other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reload+page+once

Comment: You should probably fix *that* issue instead of working around it.

Answer (score 4):

This will reload the page and store that info in localStorage, so it will happen only once

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
        if ( !localStorage["reloaded"] ){
            localStorage["reloaded"] = true
            location.reload()
        }
    }, 20000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need persistant storage accros page reloads, you will need to use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) or [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

You can do the following:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('reloaded_page_once')) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   localStorage.setItem('reloaded_page_once', true)
   window.location=window.location;
  }, 20000);
}
```

Checkout [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript) to learn more about setting/reading cookies.

Comment: Cookies are one solution. Local storage and queries strings are two others that immediately come to mind.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about local storage !